# How to take UI Automator dump for dynamic screens

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator

We are trying to automate an android screen in which there is a progress bar which gets updated every second. Our framework retrieves the UI dump using adb shell uiautomator dump to get the UI heirarchy layout and then parses the xml to take further actions. We observed that for the above mentioned screen we are not able to get the dump and the above command reports an error "Could not get idle state".

On the same screen, we tried with appium and appium is able to retrieve the elements on UI. How is appium able to retrieve the information, which UI Automator is not able to retrieve.? We would not want to integrate appium as a tool at this point in our framework and would like to use ui automator dump itself. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that Appium has 2 drivers for Android: **AndroidDriver** and **UIAutomator2Driver** (for Android 5+)

The 2nd one is a custom *client-server implementation of UIAutomator*:

https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-server

https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver

So it literally means "Appium don't use UIAutomator as is" any longer.

Google is no longer supporting UIAutomator (last release was **[july 2017](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support.test.uiautomator/uiautomator-v18)**) in favour of **Espresso**.

Check code of server part and you will understand that with `UIAutomator2` Appium overrides lots of original `UIAutomator` stuff to solve issues like you described and many more.
If you don't want to use Appium, you still can reuse **UIAutomator2 Server** or at least write your custom framework on its basis and solve issues of original UiAutomator.